# in drive Add-On (right sidebar) : Get current folder and selected Files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm currently working on a DRIVE Add-on.

I want to add a function to pick a file -> change the name -> move to a selected folder.

Do you know a way to get the current folder and selected files in my Add-on ???

Answer (score 0):

#### Accessing the current selected item

You can use the manifest to specify the following:

```
"drive": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onHomePage",
        "enabled": true
      },
      "onItemsSelectedTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "funcname"
      }
    }
```

#### The event object passed to the function

```
function funcname(e) {
   //e contains an event object


Sample Event Object:

{
      "commonEventObject": { ... },
      "drive": {
        "activeCursorItem":{
          "addonHasFileScopePermission": true,
          "id":"0B_xxxxx",
          "iconUrl": "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com...",
          "mimeType":"application/pdf",
          "title":"How to get started with Drive"
        },
        "selectedItems": [
          {
            "addonHasFileScopePermission": true,
            "id":"0B_xxxxxx",
            "iconUrl":"https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com...",
            "mimeType":"application/pdf",
            "title":"How to get started with Drive"
          },
          ...
        ]
      },
      ...
    }
```

> e.selectedItems.id contains the id of the selected item

If a file is selected you can get the id and the file and the parents will provide the current folder.  The mimeType can be used to distinguish between files and folders

[addon event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/drive/building-drive-interfaces#event_objects)

#### A simple drive addon to provide ids and mimeTypes of selected items

```
function onHomePage(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var cards = [];
  cards.push(displayFileId(e));
  return cards;
}

function displayFileId(e) {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  card.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('File Information'));
  var section = CardService.newCardSection();
  var idtxt = CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('Click on a file to get file id');
  section.addWidget(idtxt);
  card.addSection(section);
  return card.build();
}

function onMyDriveItemSelected(e) {
  var s = '';
  if (e.drive.selectedItems.length > 0) {
    e.drive.selectedItems.forEach(function(itm,i)  {
      if (i > 0) { s += '<br><br>'; }
      s += Utilities.formatString(' %s<br>%s<br> ', itm.id,itm.mimeType);
    });
  }
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  var section = CardService.newCardSection();
  var infotxt = CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(s);
  section.addWidget(infotxt);
  card.addSection(section);
  return card.build();
}
```